# get a video/gif from gym environment

Tags: python, pytorch, artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I hope you're doing well. I'm currently working on writing a code using Python and reinforcement learning to play the Breakout game in the Atari environment. The environment I'm using is Gym, and I've placed the code I've written below.

I've made a considerable effort to capture the output as a video for each episode, for example, to see how my artificial intelligence performs in episode 12. However, no matter how much I searched, I couldn't figure out how to do this.

I would appreciate it if you could guide me on how to capture video or gif from the Gym environment.

My code :

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import torch.nn.functional as F
import numpy as np
import gymnasium
from collections import namedtuple
from itertools import count
from torch.distributions import Categorical
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from gym.wrappers import RecordVideo
from PIL import Image
import PIL.ImageDraw as ImageDraw
# Define the architecture of the neural network
class Policy(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_channels=3):
        super(Policy, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(input_channels, 32, kernel_size=8, stride=4)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=4, stride=2)
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=1)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(self._conv_output_size((input_channels, 210, 160)), 512)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(512, 4)

    def _conv_output_size(self, shape):
        dummy_input = torch.zeros(1, *shape)
        x = self._conv_forward(dummy_input)
        return x.view(1, -1).size(1)

    def _conv_forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.conv1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.conv2(x))
        x = F.relu(self.conv3(x))
        return x

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self._conv_forward(x)
        x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        return F.softmax(self.fc2(x), dim=1)

# Define the experience tuple
Experience = namedtuple('Experience', ('state', 'action', 'reward'))

# Function to preprocess the input state
# Function to preprocess the input state
# Function to preprocess the input state
# Function to preprocess the input state
# Function to preprocess the input state
def preprocess(observation):
    if isinstance(observation, tuple):
        observation = observation[0]  # Extract the first element from the tuple

    state = np.array(observation)
    
    # Check if the observation is grayscale (H x W) or RGB (H x W x C)
    if len(state.shape) == 3 and state.shape[2] == 3:
        state = state.transpose(2, 0, 1)  # Change the order of dimensions (HWC to CHW)
    elif len(state.shape) == 2:
        state = np.expand_dims(state, axis=0)  # Add a batch dimension
    
    state = state.astype(np.float32)
    state = state / 255.0
    state = torch.from_numpy(state)
    state = state.unsqueeze(0)
    return state



# Function to calculate discounted rewards
def calculate_discounted_rewards(rewards, gamma=0.99):
    discounted_rewards = np.zeros_like(rewards, dtype=np.float32)
    running_add = 0
    for t in reversed(range(len(rewards))):
        running_add = running_add * gamma + rewards[t]
        discounted_rewards[t] = running_add
    return discounted_rewards

# Training function
def train(policy, optimizer, experiences):
    states = torch.cat([exp.state for exp in experiences])
    actions = torch.tensor([exp.action for exp in experiences], dtype=torch.long)
    rewards = torch.tensor(calculate_discounted_rewards([exp.reward for exp in experiences]), dtype=torch.float32)

    optimizer.zero_grad()
    action_probs = policy(states)
    selected_action_probs = action_probs.gather(1, actions.unsqueeze(1))
    loss = -torch.sum(torch.log(selected_action_probs) * rewards)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()

# Main training loop
def main():
    env = gymnasium.make('ALE/Breakout-v5')

    policy = Policy()
    optimizer = optim.Adam(policy.parameters(), lr=1e-4)

    episode_rewards = []
    episode_durations = []  # New: to store the duration of each episode
    frames = []

    for episode in range(20):  # You may need more episodes
        state = preprocess(env.reset())
        episode_experiences = []

        for t in count():
            action_probs = policy(state)
            action_distribution = Categorical(action_probs)
            action = action_distribution.sample().item()

            step_result = env.step(action)
            observation, reward, done = step_result[:3]

            next_state = preprocess(observation)

            episode_experiences.append(Experience(state, action, reward))

            if done:
                episode_rewards.append(sum(ep.reward for ep in episode_experiences))
                episode_durations.append(t + 1)  # New: store the duration
                break

            state = next_state

        train(policy, optimizer, episode_experiences)

        if episode % 10 == 0:
            print(f'Episode {episode}, Average Reward: {np.mean(episode_rewards[-10:])}')
        env.render()

    env.close()

    # Plotting
    plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
    plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
    plt.plot(episode_rewards)
    plt.title('Episode Rewards')
    plt.xlabel('Episode')
    plt.ylabel('Reward')

    plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
    plt.plot(episode_durations)
    plt.title('Episode Durations')
    plt.xlabel('Episode')
    plt.ylabel('Duration')

    plt.savefig('training_results.png')  # Save the plot as an image file

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I tried to capture video from the Gym environment and evaluate the performance of artificial intelligence, but I couldn't do it. I used several libraries, and I encountered various errors. In general, I was not familiar with how to use the libraries for this task. My Python version is also 3.11.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `RecordVideo` wrapper for this: https://gymnasium.farama.org/api/wrappers/misc_wrappers/#gymnasium.wrappers.RecordVideo

For example, this will record every 1000th episode:

```py
from gymnasium.wrappers import RecordVideo
trigger = lambda t: t % 1000 == 0
base_env = gymnasium.make('ALE/Breakout-v5')
env = RecordVideo(base_env, video_folder="./videos", episode_trigger=trigger, disable_logger=True)
```